# SOLR sort by relevancy

Tags: sorting, solr, relevance

I need to sort a solr result by relevancy. I used the following code for sort:

`fq={!tag=resourcetag}(post_type:resource AND (siec_database_item:no OR siec_database_item:"") )&showposts=10&solrsearch=1&paged=0&sortby=score desc`

But it didn't get any result. I searched the web but received only theory about relevancy sort. I need some practical solution.

Comment: By default all documents in the result set are sorted based on score value, in desc order. document with highest score will be first in result.

Comment: Do you think my query is correct? or it is better to use `fl=*%2Cscore` instead of `sortby=score desc`

Comment: `sort=score asc|desc` check my answer for reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FYI showing one example 
I am just using id and score field for `fl`

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/test/select?fl=id,score&indent=on&q=ipod&wt=json
```

for query `q=ipod` we have 6 documents returned from solr, here is how it looks. You can notice docs are sorted on relevancy score value.(desc order, default)

```
response":{"numFound":6,"start":0,"maxScore":4.391201,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"IW-02",
        "score":4.391201},
      {
        "id":"F8V7067-APL-KIT",
        "score":4.1061177},
      {
        "id":"09",
        "score":3.690675},
      {
        "id":"01",
        "score":3.597126},
      {
        "id":"3007WFRD",
        "score":3.1348155},
      {
        "id":"MA147LL/A",
        "score":1.9562671}]
```

if you want results in ascending order, just add sort param to url `&sort=score asc` and results will change. you can do the same sorting with other fields as well. (ex: sort=price asc).

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the exact same problem, I did lot of R&D and came up with my own solution of relevancy search.

Please have a look at the solution:

https://blog.knoldus.com/2016/12/13/solr-relevance-search-using-solrj-in-scala/

and the question I asked on Stack Overflow:

[relevance search in Solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015743/relevance-search-in-solr)